Is this normal sliding glass door behavior?
Water is leaking through the bottom of the door (video here) when there's heavy rain. According to the builder, they're saying this is normal and the track is there to catch the water and have it drain back out (which it does do), but I've never seen water come through any door frame like this before. Is this normal? If not, what would the fix be?

I have two sliding doors and a number of sliding windows.  The only time rain/water was on the inside was when I forgot to close a window/door.

Twice in the past 30 years I've had to recaulk around my 50-year old sliding glass doors. This includes running a putty knife under the flashing to clean that out and reseal under the flashing. Water should not be getting inside the house.

Ok, that's what I figured. These are pretty much brand new doors, less than a year old, so it seemed weird to me.

sliding glass doors are not fully waterproof. However it looks like the drains that should be on the outside of the track may be blocked allowing water to build up.  Take a look at the outside. You may need to do this during a good rain to see what is happening.

I didn't notice anything out of the ordinary on the outside today, but yeah maybe I have to check while it's raining. If anything it seemed like the water was coming through directly under the door (it's not a door that opens).

Why does it matter if it's normal or not?  your warranty should cover all faults  not just the things the builder doesn't normally mess up.

Can you see where the track's drains are?

There's a couple of these weep holes at the corner of the frame on the outside. I think that's where it was draining.
